# Search string inside array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I am looking for a simple function to check if a specific string is inside my array.

```
function checkRegion(departement){
    var region = '';

    if(alsace.indexOf(departement) != -1)
    {
        region = "alsace";
    }
    if(aquitaine.indexOf(departement) != -1){
        region = "aquitaine";
    }
    if(auvergne.indexOf(departement) != -1){
        region = "auvergne";
    }
    if(basseNormandie.indexOf(departement) != -1){
       region = "basse-normandie";
    }
    if(iledefrance.indexOf(departement) != -1){
        region = "ile-de-france";
    }else{
        region = 'undennnnnfined';
    }

    return region;
};
```

Any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: So what is your problem? Does your function work? What is `alsace`, `aquitaine`, `auvergne`, ... .

Comment: My function not working, it always return "undefinnnned"... (alsace, aquitaine etc.... are array of string)

Comment: Function supposed to search if a string "departement" is inside one of those array (alsace, aquitaine, auvergne etc...). When we have a match it should add specific word in variable "region" and return it

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Where do you define **`alsace`**, **`aquinaine`**, **`auvergne`**, **`basseNormandie`**, **`iledefrance`**? They must be arrays, but we'll need their code if you want us to be of any assistance.

Comment: provided code does not provide any research.  put here your variable values also .

Comment: Your code is always executing the last `if` statement, which will set region to 'undennnnnfined' if departement is not in iledefrance, no matter the result of the previous conditions. Just replace your `region = 'xxx';`statements with `return 'xxx';`

Comment: alsace, aquitaine etc... is defined as array outside function.

Comment: Check [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/vez8b5bh/)

Comment: @Mohammad your code is working but if i modify the variable it does not anymore keep getting undefinnnned https://jsfiddle.net/vez8b5bh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in the **use of consecutive `if` statements without chaining them together** to make a complete check.

Doing it your way, **the code actually completely disregards all the `if` statements, but the last one**.

So, if **`iledefrance.indexOf(departement) != -1`** gives **`false`**, it'will always execute the code inside **`else`**, meaning it'll set **`region = 'undennnnnfined'`**.

---

**Note:**

In the code, I replaced **`!= -1`** with **`~`** as it makes for a somewhat more succinct code. In essence, it will convert **`-1`** to **`0`**, namely **`false`**.

Be sure to check out [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) for more if you are not familiar.

---

• **1<sup>st</sup> Option** :

Try chaining your **`if`** statements together in an **`if/else if/else`** format as follows:

```
function checkRegion(departement){
    var region = '';

    if(~alsace.indexOf(departement)) {
        region = "alsace";
    }
    else if(~aquitaine.indexOf(departement)) {
        region = "aquitaine";
    }
    else if(~auvergne.indexOf(departement)) {
        region = "auvergne";
    }
    else if(~basseNormandie.indexOf(departement)) {
        region = "basse-normandie";
    }
    else if(~iledefrance.indexOf(departement)) {
        region = "ile-de-france";
    }
    else{
        region = 'undennnnnfined';
    }
    return region;
};
```

---

• **2<sup>nd</sup> Option** :

Create two arrays:

- One should contain your region arrays (**`alsace`**, **`aquitaine`** etc) &
- One more containing the names of your arrays as strings, so that you can return the appropriate string based on the array that was evaluated as true.

**Code:**

```
function checkRegion(departement) {
    var
       regions = [alsace, aquitaine, auvergne, basseNormandie, iledefrance],
       regionsNames = ["alsace", "aquitaine", "auvergne", "basseNormandie", "iledefrance"];

    for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
        if (~regions[i].indexOf(departement)) {
            return regionsNames[i];
        }
    }
    return "undennnnnfined"; // If the 'for' loop doesn't return anything, it's false.
};
```

---

**Demos:**

- Working demo with the 1<sup>st</sup> solution → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9v8n9vf9/).
- Working demo with the 2<sup>nd</sup> solution → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/73y1crja/).

---

**Snippets:**

- Snippet with the 1<sup>st</sup> solution:

```js
function checkRegion(departement){
    var region = '';

    if(~alsace.indexOf(departement)) {
        region = "alsace";
    }
    else if(~aquitaine.indexOf(departement)) {
        region = "aquitaine";
    }
    else if(~auvergne.indexOf(departement)) {
        region = "auvergne";
    }
    else if(~basseNormandie.indexOf(departement)) {
       region = "basse-normandie";
    }
    else if(~iledefrance.indexOf(departement)) {
        region = "ile-de-france";
  }
    else{
        region = 'undennnnnfined';
    }
    return region;
};

var
   alsace = ["Strasbourg", "Colmar"],
   aquitaine = ["Gironde", "Landes", "Dordogne", "Pyrenees-Atlantiques", "Lot-et-Garonne"],
   auvergne = [],
   basseNormandie = [],
   iledefrance = [];
   
alert(checkRegion("Strasbourg"));
```

- Snippet with the 2<sup>nd</sup> solution:

```js
function checkRegion(departement) {
    var
       regions = [alsace, aquitaine, auvergne, basseNormandie, iledefrance],
       regionsNames = ["alsace", "aquitaine", "auvergne", "basseNormandie", "iledefrance"];

    for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
        if (~regions[i].indexOf(departement)) {
            return regionsNames[i];
        }
    }
    return "undennnnnfined"; // If the 'for' loop doesn't return anything, it's false.
};

var
   alsace = ["Strasbourg", "Colmar"],
   aquitaine = ["Gironde", "Landes", "Dordogne", "Pyrenees-Atlantiques", "Lot-et-Garonne"],
   auvergne = [],
   basseNormandie = [],
   iledefrance = [];
   
alert(checkRegion("Strasbourg"));
```